# how we can use web socket from multiple IP addresses in JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, signalr

I need to connect and send request for websocket from different IPs in jmeter to my singalR server. How can I do it. I know in case of HTTP request we can do that in jmeter by creating multiple IP addresses alias on the machine as mentioned in the link https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-send-jmeter-requests-from-different-ips.
How this process will work for websockets.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not as the possibility to set outgoing IP address needs to be present in the WebSocket plugin you're using.

Currently available solution is to allocate as many machines as IP addresses you need and [run JMeter in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/). If a single machine is powerful enough you can kick off several JMeter slave processes there, keep in mind that:

- you need to have these IP addresses (or aliases) defined at OS level
- you need to bind the slaves to [different ports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)

If you can do Java programming you can add it yourself, the project lives at https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers, somewhere [here](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/luminis/websocket/WebSocketClient.java#L227)

If you cannot - you can ask the plugin developer to add this feature either via GitHub or try reaching out to him via [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I am not a java developer but if I change in the code myself then there is need to add the relevant UI element in the JMeter as well to mention source IP address. I have added request in the Jmeter plugin support let see how it goes. Is there any other tool like jmeter that can address this issue?